# group action on topological space induces group action on cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, sheaf-cohomology, abelian-varieties

I have two questions about group actions on topological spaces.

Suppose we have a free, properly discontinuous left group action, $G$ acts on a Hausdorff space $X$. We want to show that there is a homomorphism from $H^p(G,H^0(X,\pi^*\mathscr{F}))$ to $H^p(X/G,\mathscr{F})$, where $\mathscr{F}$ is a  sheaf on $X/G$.

Firstly, we define the $G$-action on $H^0(X,\pi^*\mathscr{F})$. From the Appendix B in *Abelian varieties* by Mumford, or Appendix B in *Complex Abelian varieties* by H.Lange, given a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X/G$, we have a left G-action on $H^0(X,\pi^*\mathscr{F})$, where $\pi:X\rightarrow X/G$. Then how does G act on $H^0(X,\pi^*\mathscr{F})$ exactly?
Is it like the following?

Suppose that $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an open covering of $X/G$ such that $\pi^{-1}(V_i)={\bigcup}_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(U_i)$, where $\pi|_{U_i}:U_i\cong V_i$ is a homeomorphism. Then $g\in G$ acts on $\prod\limits_{i\in I}\prod\limits_{\sigma\in G}\pi^*\mathscr{F}(\sigma(U_i))$ by sending $(f_{i\sigma})_{i\in I,\sigma\in G}$ to $(f_{i(g\sigma)})_{i\in I,\sigma\in G}$, since  $\pi^*\mathscr{F}(\sigma(U_i)) = \mathscr{F}(V_i)$, which will induce left $G$-action on $H^0(X,\pi^*\mathscr{F})$.

If the $G$-action is like above, then there will be a problem in H.Lange's book, P414, the first line, $$\lambda_{ij}\lambda_{jk}=\lambda_{ik}$$ We notice that $\lambda_{ij}$ is from a subset of $W_i$ to a subset of $W_j$, then right hand side from $W_i$ to $W_k$, but left hand side doesn't make any sense. If we make the equality right, it is $$\lambda_{jk}\lambda_{ij}=\lambda_{ik}$$ Then there will be a problem with the $G$-action on $H^0(X,\pi^*\mathscr{F})$ when we try to prove the theorem, which is that we cannot show the morphisms forms a morphism of complexes. In Mumford's book, P23, it says that it is easy to check.

The second problem is how good X could be, that will allow $X/G$ to have a open covering $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ that has the properties in Mumford's book, P23? Mainly property 2. And how to prove it?

Thanks. And I hope I make my questions clear.

Complementary: about $\lambda_{ij}$ and $W_i$, I should change $W_i$ to $U_i$ for being consistent, then in H.Lange's book, using the language in Mumford's book:

There is an open covering $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X/G$ such that

1. $\pi^{-1}(V_i)={\bigcup}_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(U_i)$, where $\pi_i =\pi|_{U_i}:U_i\cong V_i$ is a homeomorphism.
2. For any $i,j \in I$, there exists at most one $\lambda \in G$ such that $U_j \bigcap \lambda U_i \not = \emptyset$, call it $\lambda_{ij}$ if it exists.

We can check, if $V_i\bigcap V_j \bigcap V_k \not = \emptyset$, in the book,
$$\lambda_{ij}\lambda_{jk}=\lambda_{ik}$$
It's not correct by the directions of the maps. So we change it to $$\lambda_{jk}\lambda_{ij}=\lambda_{ik}$$

Next thing is to define a morphism of complexes. Take $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{O}_X^\star$ for example, where $X$ is a complex manifold. For $f \in C^1(G, H^0(\mathscr{O}_X^\star))$, $\phi_1(f) \in C^1(\{V_i\}_{i\in I},\mathscr{O}_{X/G}^\star)$ defined as $\{V_i\bigcap V_j,g_{ij}\}$, $g_{ij}(x) = f(\lambda_{ij},\pi_i^{-1}(x))$.

For $F \in C^2(G, H^0(\mathscr{O}_X^\star))$, $\phi_2(F) \in C^2(\{V_i\}_{i\in I},\mathscr{O}_{X/G}^\star)$ defined as $\{V_i\bigcap V_j \bigcap V_j,G_{ijk}\}$, $G_{ijk}(x) = F(\lambda_{ij},\lambda_{jk},\pi_i^{-1}(x))$.

Then the problem is that, it's not a moprhism of complexes, if we change the order of the $\lambda$'s equality.

Answer (score 2):

In general you wan the action of $G$ on $H^0(X,\pi^*\mathcal{F})$ to come from basic cohomology functoriality. Here it is : let $g:X\rightarrow X$ be any element of the group. Then there is a morphism of sheaves $\pi^*\mathcal{F}\rightarrow g_*g^*\pi^*\mathcal{F}$. We have $g^*\pi^*=\pi^*$, and taking $H^0$ : $$g^*:H^0(X,\pi^*\mathcal{F})\rightarrow H^0(X,g_*g^*\pi_*\mathcal{F})=H^0(X,g_*\pi^*\mathcal{F})=H^0(X,\pi^*\mathcal{F})$$ where the last equality is follows from the definition of the pushforward. (I denote the map on cohomology by $g^*$ because it is standard, but it may leads to some confusion as this is not the same thing as the pullback functor).

This is a right action because cohomology is contravariant : indeed the composition will come from 
$$ \pi^*\mathcal{F}\rightarrow g_*g^*\pi^*\mathcal{F}\rightarrow g_*h_*h^*g^*\pi^*\mathcal{F}=(gh)_*(gh)^*\pi^*\mathcal{F}$$
Taking $H^0$, $h^*g^*=(gh)^*$.

If you want a left action instead, you will need to look at the action of $g^{-1}$ instead. Maybe this is the thing which is troubling you as books may prefer the right action (a bit more natural) while others might prefer to stick with left ones.

---

Now that we have an action, we can see how it looks like, for example on open sets of the form $\bigsqcup_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(U)$ where $p:U\rightarrow V$ is an isomorphism.

If you write down all the definitions, you will see that this is what you wrote.

I don't have the books so I can't say more. I don't know what the $\lambda_{ij}$ and the $W_i$ are. Maybe you can expand your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your point is very clear. From your point, the action is right, and you say that it's the same as what I defined, but I think it is left, I will check it again. As for the rest, I will expand the question.

Comment: @yulincai Your action is indeed left, and it is the left action associated to the right action I defined.